# what problems. does not display comments django

Tags: python, django

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Article, Comment
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    latest_articles_list = Article.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    return render(request, 'articles/list.html', {'latest_articles_list': latest_articles_list})


def detail(request, article_id):
    try:
        a = Article.objects.get( id = article_id )
    except:
        raise Http404('Статья не найдена')

    latest_comments_list = a.comment_set.order_by('-id')[:10]
    return render(request, 'articles/detail.html', {'article': a, 'latest_comments_list':latest_comments_list})
```

template

```
{% if latest_comments_list %}

    {% for c in latest_comments_list %}
    <p>
        <strong>{{c.author_name}}</strong>
        <p>{{c.comment_text}}</p>

    </p>
    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
Комментарии не найдены!
{% endif %}
```

Comment: can you share your models too

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is considered most helpful to describe your exact problem, maybe a description of what you already tried and a helpful [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The better your question (quality, not quantity), the better and quicker the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Considering You have a foreign key of Article Model in Comments Model.

What you need to do is somewhat like this:

```
latest_comments_list = Comment.objects.filter(article_id__in = [art['id] for art in a]).order_by('-id')
```

Also you might consider taking a look at [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) query form django